# React.JS | create-react-app load times are insanely high, takes an hour to make a react app

Tags: reactjs, time, load, create-react-app

These Are my PC Specs:
processor: intel i3 2100
ram: 4 gigs
gpu intel integrated 2000

Every time i try to make a react app using `npx create-react-app <my-app>`, it takes way too long, this time it took over an hour, besides it just gets stuck on idealTree: react-dom for like 30 minutes, i have tried closing every other program while creating my react app but it still takes as long

is there any way to speed up this process without hardware upgrades?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create one template for every react application you gonna make.
So the next time, instead of creating a new application with
`npx create-react-app <my-app>` and waiting for a long time, you can work on an '**empty**' react app already created and speed up the process.

Hope you find it helpful!